# math lib native Visual c++

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, math

I am working in a project that follow DO-178C level C.
The planing is to use C programing language.
A lot of concerns arise about the libraries in the C language.

The math library is native of the Microsoft Visual Studio?
Must all c compileres implement the math library?
How can I see what Microsoft C compiler implements? Does it follow a standard?

Thanks

Comment: Math.h is included in every compiler as far as I know. Visual Studio have C compiler and it can be access via Visual Studio console(search in start menu programs) and compiler itself is "cl.exe"

Comment: It is a standard that governs what kind of software you can use to make an airplane fly.  They are kinda... strict about that.  When you find yourself in a situation where you have to post to an Internet Q+A site to find help about it then... you might be doing it wrong.  You won't find a lot of SO users that want to fly in the plane you wrote the software for.  Surely that makes sense to you?  Do mention the company you work for, please.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean when you refer to the "math library"? Do you mean those parts of the standard C library that are defined and/or declared in the `math.h` header file?

If so, then:

1) The C library is usually provided by the OS for runtime dynamic linking. The compiler implementation usually provides any necessary libraries and headers for use by developers.

2) Usually the compiler implementation will provide all standard libraries and headers. On Windows, some compilers may be set up to use the standard libraries provided by the OS instead of providing their own implementation. Visual Studio is provided by the same vendor as the OS, so from that perspective it's all the same thing, pretty much.

3) By referencing the documentation provided by Microsoft

4) Does what follow a standard? The "Microsoft Visual Studio" C/C++ compiler? Like pretty much every compiler, the default mode is not exactly conforming with any standard (compilers always provide "features" and extensions) but there is a way to tell the compiler that you want it to conform to the C Standard. The "math library"? As much as the compiler as a whole conforms, so will the math library conform.

Note, of course, that the C standard that Microsoft Visual Studio's C compiler conforms to (when run in conforming mode) is ISO/IES 9899:1989, commonly called C89. This standard has been obsolete for over ten years, and its successor version has already been obsoleted. (ISO/IEC 9899:1989 was replaced in 1999 by ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (called "C99"), which was itself replaced in 2011 by ISO/IEC 9899:2011, called "C11".)